# CSS hover not changing other element when specified to do so

Tags: html, css, hover

I am having issues with CSS on hover effects. When hovering over box1, it should change boxText to have the animation 'fadeIn' with a duration, iteration count, and fill.

I tried removing the animation factor and simply changing it to a background color which did not work. However, when I just made the hover affect box1 and not boxText, the animation worked.

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    color: transparent;
  }
  to {
    color: black;
  }
}

.box1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(73, 170, 255);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.boxText {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.box1:hover .boxText {
  animation: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="textBox1">
  <p class="boxText">
    Test
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: In your HTML `<p class="boxText">` is not a descendant of of `<div class="box1"/>`, that's why the CSS selector doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the selector like this :

> .box1:hover .boxText

wich meansn **boxText** must be a child of **box1**

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {color: transparent;}
    to {color: black;}
}

.box1 {
    width:70px;
    height:40px;
    background-color: rgb(73, 170, 255);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.boxText {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.box1:hover .boxText{
    animation: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
<div class="textBox1">
<p class="boxText">
Test
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without being a child of box1?

Comment: Yes you can use javascript to obtain the same result but not with Plain CSS.